# Getting some errors when uploading project to server

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm trying to learn how to implement a user account system into my project. I found some source code for a simple user account system and decided to upload it to my server just to test it and see how it would be behave.

After uploading it, I'm getting [these two errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7Hbm.png).

Both of the errors are referring to my `db.php` file but everything seems to connected in the right way. I'm using 5.7.19 MySQL Community Server (GPL). I can post my other files too if need be, I just assume that it has something to do with the two files below. How can I resolve these issues?

db.php:

```
<?php

$db = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

?>
```

config.php:

```
<?php

define("DB_HOST" ,"localhost");
define("DB_USER" ,"root");
define("DB_PASS" ,"root");
define("DB_NAME" ,"registration");

?>
```

Comment: Is `config.php` included BEFORE `dp.php`? You may be better off just showing us how you handle that actually.

Comment: Also, post the actual error messages in the question, not a picture to them, please.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Yes, config.php is included before db.php on all of my files. Sorry about the picture.

Comment: Why not just use regular variables? `$DB_HOST = "localhost";` etc and `$db = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);` Assuming you only need to access these variables on the initial pageload whenever connecting to the database.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton This is code that was downloaded and then uploaded to a server. I did not write this. I wanted to see how it would work as an example. Then I got those errors I mentioned.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Pure variables are not the best solution. In normal projects, the connection to the database is made within the class (for example, the factory pattern). It is therefore necessary to have a config-reader.

Answer (score 0):

First, these are warnings, not errors. Your [configuration](http://php.net/manual/pl/function.error-reporting.php) `error_reporting` [display it](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) users.

The first one is probably because you have a version of the library for another version of the server.

The second one tells you that you do not provide a valid login and password.

The rest of the script does not execute properly because you have no connection to the database.

As you can [read in the PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php) you should check that you are properly connected to the database.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');

/*
 * This is the "official" OO way to do it,
 * BUT $connect_error was broken until PHP 5.2.9 and 5.3.0.
 */
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '
            . $mysqli->connect_error);
}
```